# Перевод десятичной дроби в обычную Java

Tags: java, строки, float

Нужна функция которая принимает `float` и возвращает `string` в виде дроби 1/3 и тому подобные

Например:  `func(0.5) = 1/2`

Было пару идей, но кажется можно сделать в разы проще и "умнее"
Подскажите как лучше всего это реализовать?

Comment: проще всего - записать `f * 10^k/10^k` потом сократить на общий множитель и всё. Только учитывайте погрешность хранения данных...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class Fraction {
    private static final double ratio = 0.01;

    public static String get(double val) {
        for (int i = 1;; i++) {
            double tem = val / (1D / i);
            if (Math.abs(tem - Math.round(tem)) < ratio)
                return Math.round(tem) + "/" + i;
        }    
    }
}
```

или можно не изобретать велосипед и использовать [Fraction](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/fraction.html) из [Apache Commons Math](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/).